# add a condition for entry between open and close

Tags: pine-script

helloo friends, can somebody help be with adding a condition where close[len] is between open and close of starpoint. so basically this code draws a divergence line between 2 candles, what I want is that the second candle close is between the first one open and close.
in the following if statement

```
               ((cond == 1 and src[startpoint] > src[len] and prsc[startpoint] < nz(array.get(pl_vals, x))) or
               (cond == 2 and src[startpoint] < src[len] and prsc[startpoint] > nz(array.get(pl_vals, x))))
```

Here's the divergence code block

````
// Check if we get new Pivot High Or Pivot Low
float ph = pivothigh((source == "Close" ? close : high), prd, prd)
float pl = pivotlow((source == "Close" ? close : low), prd, prd)
plotshape(ph and showpivot, text = "H",  style = shape.labeldown, color = color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor = color.red, location = location.abovebar, offset = -prd)
plotshape(pl and showpivot, text = "L",  style = shape.labelup, color = color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor = color.lime, location = location.belowbar, offset = -prd)

// keep values and positions of Pivot Highs/Lows in the arrays
var int maxarraysize = 20
var ph_positions = array.new_int(maxarraysize, 0)
var pl_positions = array.new_int(maxarraysize, 0)
var ph_vals = array.new_float(maxarraysize, 0.)
var pl_vals = array.new_float(maxarraysize, 0.)

// add PHs to the array
if ph
    array.unshift(ph_positions, bar_index)
    array.unshift(ph_vals, ph)
    if array.size(ph_positions) > maxarraysize
        array.pop(ph_positions)
        array.pop(ph_vals)

// add PLs to the array
if pl
    array.unshift(pl_positions, bar_index)
    array.unshift(pl_vals, pl)
    if array.size(pl_positions) > maxarraysize
        array.pop(pl_positions)
        array.pop(pl_vals)

// functions to check Regular Divergences and Hidden Divergences

// function to check positive regular or negative hidden divergence
// cond == 1 => positive_regular, cond == 2=> negative_hidden
positive_regular_positive_hidden_divergence(src, cond)=>
    divlen = 0
    prsc = source == "Close" ? close : low
    // if indicators higher than last value and close price is higher than las close 
    if dontconfirm or src > src[1] or close > close[1]
        startpoint = dontconfirm ? 0 : 1 // don't check last candle
        // we search last 15 PPs
        for x = 0 to maxpp - 1
            len = bar_index - array.get(pl_positions, x) + prd
            // if we reach non valued array element or arrived 101. or previous bars then we don't search more
            if array.get(pl_positions, x) == 0 or len > maxbars
                break
            if len > 5 and 
               ((cond == 1 and src[startpoint] > src[len] and prsc[startpoint] < nz(array.get(pl_vals, x))) or
               (cond == 2 and src[startpoint] < src[len] and prsc[startpoint] > nz(array.get(pl_vals, x))))
                slope1 = (src[startpoint] - src[len]) / (len - startpoint)
                virtual_line1 = src[startpoint] - slope1
                slope2 = (close[startpoint] - close[len]) / (len - startpoint)
                virtual_line2 = close[startpoint] - slope2
                arrived = true
                for y = 1 + startpoint to len - 1
                    if src[y] < virtual_line1 or nz(close[y]) < virtual_line2
                        arrived := false
                        break
                    virtual_line1 := virtual_line1 - slope1
                    virtual_line2 := virtual_line2 - slope2
                
                if arrived
                    divlen := len
                    break
    divlen```


Tried solutions :
(close[len] < open[startpoint] and close[len] > close[startpoint)

close[len] > min(open[startpoint], close[startpoint]) and close[len] < max(open[startpoint], close[startpoint])
````